# SQL comparing date in column against system date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a column `st_duedate` that has multiple dates.

I want to compare these dates against the system date and add a column for when they are due.

I currently have the below code in SSMS that looks for dates before system date and current system date.

```
CASE 
    WHEN st_duedate < GETDATE() THEN 'Overdue'
    WHEN st_duedate = GETDATE() THEN 'Due Today'
END AS 'Due when'
```

I want to add a "Due within 7 days" and "Due after 7 days" to this "Due when" column. So looking at `between > system date and <= 7` for "Due within 7 days" and then `system date > 7` for "Due after 7 days".

I have tried `GETDATE()+7` and `between` which doesn't work...can anyone help me with this please? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DATEDIFF function.

```sql
CASE 
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,st_duedate,getdate()) <= 7 THEN 'Due within 7 Days'
WHEN DATEDIFF(day,st_duedate,getdate()) > 7 THEN 'Due after 7 Days'
END AS 'Due when'
```

Comment: `DATEDIIF` of course!! Thank you for this! I am getting however getting "Due within 7 days" for 03 May one, but I think that's because I converted this to `CONVERT(varchar, ST_DUEDATE, 106)` prior to this....however that's this question answered thank you! If I can't figure this new issue out I'll post a new question :)

Comment: Actually it looks like everyone over the system date states "Due within 7 days" even if the `st_duedate` is far in the distance.....I presume I would need to ask another question and not combine with this one?